# Where is /tmp folder located in Airflow?

Tags: airflow

I know that we can share information between tasks by persisting data to /tmp location. Since every task could run on a different machine. How is /tmp from one task is available to the other task in the Airflow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sharing you mentioned is only possible if you use `LocalExecutor` - because all tasks run on the same machine in this case.

If you use Celery/Kubernetes executors, the "/tmp" data share will not work. It might work accidentaly on Celery Executor if the tasks are executed on the same machine, but this is not at all guaranteed. You could potentially put all the tasks that need such sharing on a single machine, in Celery Executor using "queues" - when you create a single celery worker for one queue, all tasks assigned to that queue will be executed on that machine (thus /tmp sharing will work), but this hevily impacts scalability and resilience scenarios.

And also you could have Airlfow Deployment where `/tmp` is put on a shared filesystem, but this would be terribly inefficient as "/tmp" folder is often used for local caching of files and using a network filesystem there would severly impact performance.